# How to make a parent interface who has some annotations from children using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a lot of model classes who has same annotations like that:

**Child:**

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "STATUS")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, doNotUseGetters = 
true)
public class Child{...}
```

**Parent:**

```
public @interface Parent
{...}
```

I want to set annotations in parent. So child implements in one simple annotation @Parent

And how to pass the parameters from Child To Parent?

Comment: Spring is not involved at all in the code you posted. The annotations are Lombok annotations, and JPA annotations.

Comment: Have you just tried adding the annotations to `Parent` and annotating `Child` with `@Parent`?

Comment: I mean annotation. I just want to know the sintax to do it.

Comment: Yes Samuel, but i want to know the sintax to do it correclty and how is the better way to not repeat the model annotations every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the annotations to the `Parent` annotation:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "STATUS")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, doNotUseGetters = true)
public @interface Parent {
}
```

And use it in you `Child` class:

```
@Parent
public class Child {
}
```